# Connection between second derivative and zero of the function

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Let's have a function f in $\mathbb{R}$ which is twice differentiable. Then the task is, if $f''$ is positive for all $x$ then $f$ hast 2 points where it is zero at max.

My "proof" is as such: If $f''>0$ then $f'$ is strict montone growing. Thus there are three cases, either $f'$ is always positive, or always negative, or goes from negative to positive.

The worst case would be if it goes from negative to positive, then $f'$ has a point where it is zero (intermediate value theorem). Therefore $\mathbb{R}$ could be split into two intervals
Let $x_1$ the point where $f'$ is zero. First interval $(-\infty,x_1)$ and $(x_1,\infty)$, So f is decreasing in the first interval (if f goes under the x-axis then it has a point where it is zero) and increasing in the second intervall (if it then surpasses the x-axis it has again a point where f is zero) thus there are at a max to points where f is zero. Is the proof correct, could it be shorter ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it true? What about $x^2 + 1$?

Comment: therefore "at a max" it does not nead to gave have 2, exp(x) is antoher example

Comment: I see, I interpreted it to mean there are two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1)\leq 0$ and $f(x_2)\leq 0$. You should say, "f has, at most, 2 point where it is $0$".

Answer (score 1):

This proof is perfectly correct, one other way to see it is through the Rolle Theorem, if a function has the same value on two points, then its derivative is 0 between those points. By recurrence, you can see that if a function has n zeros, its derivative has at least n-1 zeros, his second derivative at least n-2 and so on an so forth. So if your function had at least 3 zeros, its second derivative would cancel at least once which is not possible with your hypothesis.

Your proof is more general because it also works if f'' is zero on a countable number of points.

Comment: Is the other implication true as well? So if derivative zero at one point, then there are 2 point a.b with f(a)=f(b)

Comment: Look at f(x) = x^3, it's derivative vanishes at 0 but it is strictly monotone.

Comment: yeah absolutely right, thanks Dean :)